# How can I access a website that are using cloudflare?

Tags: php, cloudflare

I am having a problem with my curl script for accessing a website that has a cloudflare.

It was working before when the site wasn't using cloudflare.

I also have in my script what browser i am using.

```
curl_setopt ($ch2, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
```

When I open the php script.

I'm stuck on

```
Checking your browser before accessing xrshellbooter.com.
DDoS protection by CloudFlare
```

so it doesn't allow me to access the site.

Comment: It probably uses JavaScript to verify that you are indeed a browser and not a bot.

Comment: Though you can always do some tricks to make it look like a normal request.

Comment: Do you have permission to access the site this way? If so, contact the site admin and ask whether they've moved the data you need into an XML feed.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare has a javascript enabled page that is turned on by a website owner, and designed to only allow actual working browsers with javascript enabled to enter the website. You need to ask the owner of the CloudFlare account to whitelist the IP you are attempting to make the request from. 
Your configuration and code should work after that

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a little old...but I'll respond...

Whatever you are doing is triggering a DDoS trigger & the interstitial page you are seeing is checking to make sure you're not a bot. You should have the site owner whitelist the IP(s) the calls are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If you own the domain you can whitelist your own server IP in CloudFlare and you shouldn't see the DDoS protection screen again.

Answer (score -4):

If the site is http://www.example.com, you can use http://direct.example.com

Comment: Yes I tried site http://www.example.com, http://www.directexample.com both gives the exact same problem.

Comment: Bit old, but technology for this haven't changed yet:
direct.example.com is another DNS record, and as a self-respecting site owner, I don't bother to add a DNS entry for "direct".